# Java error class [D cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable ([D and java.lang.Comparable are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'). why?

Tags: java

I ran out of room in the title, so I will explain more here.  In my code, I am trying to find where the highest value lies in the array.  I get an exception on the binary search.  Can anybody help me figure out why this is happening?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;

public class Q {

    static double [][] Q = {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };
    static int state = 0 - 0;
    static int next = 0; 
    static int reward = 0; 
    static int action = 0; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println(state);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000   ; i++) {
            System.out.println("new");
        int rand = (int) (Math.random()* 4) + 1;
        rand = rand - 1;
        if(((int)Math.random() *2) + 1 == 1) {
        if(Q[state][0] == Q[state][1] && 
                Q[state][1] == Q[state][2] && 
                Q[state][2] == Q[state][3]//0 && 
                        ) {
            //  Q[state][3]);
        action = rand;
        } else {
            action = Arrays.binarySearch(Q,
                    Math.max(Q[state][0], Math.max(Q[state][1], Math.max(Q[state][2], Q[state][3]))));
        }
        }//
        //
        //
    //  M////
        else {
            action = rand;
        }
```

I have no idea why this error randomely started happening.

Comment: You're calling `Arrays.binarySearch(Q, ...)`, but `Q` is a `double[][]`. A two-dimensional array is an array of arrays. And `double[]` does not implement `Comparable`. Perhaps you mean to pass `Q[state]`?

Comment: I just have one more question.  This value always returns 31.  WDo you know why this is?

Comment: I would assume it's because every element in each array is `0`. I don't see where you assign new values to the arrays. Though also note that binary search only works on a sorted array.